# How should I diagnose ERROR 1045 during MySQL installation?

Tags: mysql

I recently setup a MySQL server and encounted the following error when I ran the mysql console (and incidentally the administrator GUI tool):

ERROR 1045: Access denied for user: 'root@localhost' (Using password: YES)

I had done a standard installation and reached the last page in the configuration wizard when the security check stage failed with an error suggesting that the MySQL port was blocked by a firewall.

closed the wizard, checked there was no firewall running and then and tried running mysql and the administrator GUI and found the same error in both cases.

Can anyone suggest a solution to the problem or perhaps resources for diagnosing MySQL problems.

Comment: MySQL 1045 is explained here: http://www.webyog.com/faq/content/23/18/en/error-no-1045-connection-denied.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to reset your root password. I had a similar problem a while back.

Details: [How to reset the root password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html)

The basic process involves stopping the server and restarting it with a special initialization script.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly.  I do wonder what the installer did to incorrectly set the root password.  I would blame myself using the wrong password, but it actually failed from the config wizard where you set the thing.

Answer (score 0):

1045 is generally "access denied".  See the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/access-denied.html) for suggestions about how to deal with this.

Comment: Heh, I noticed that 1045 mapped to "access denied" when I read the message "ERROR 1045: Access denied ...".