# MySql service stops under 2008 r2 x64

Tags: windows-server-2008, mysql, configuration

I have installed MySql 5.5 server under windows 2008r2 x64

Apparently I can see that MySql service stops even if is configured to start automatically

What can I do to find out why this is happening?

MySql database is used as backend of ASP.Net web site

Is it possible that web site was not active for a while and system stop mysql service?

**Update**: It was mysql-5.5.7-rc-winx64. I could be an issue with this version (release candidate).

Now I am trying to install mysql-5.5.8-winx64

And I have an issue with configuring MySql to work using name pipes
   I did uncheck use of TCP/IP protocol and configuration wizard just hangs

**Update**: I have found workaround. It is required to configure MySql to use TCP/IP first, then reconfigure to use named pipes

It looks like this link also has some information about the possible problems [How should I diagnose ERROR 1045 during MySQL installation?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1923/how-should-i-diagnose-error-1045-during-mysql-installation)

**Update**: run mysql_upgrade to fix 2 errors issue after upgrade. [MySQL 5.5.8](http://filepig.org/download/mysql/changelog/) updates details

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same.
This is what I did to resolve the matter, and indeed it worked out.

Find your my.ini file. (normaly under /mysql/bin folder.

Edit this file, and you will see something like this...

```
# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
basedir                 = "/Arquivos de Programas/XAMMP/xampp/mysql/"
datadir                 = "/Arquivos de Programas/XAMMP/xampp/mysql/data/"
port              = 3306
socket              = "MySQL"
```

All I did, is this:

```
# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
basedir                 = "d:/Arquivos de Programas/XAMMP/xampp/mysql/"
datadir                 = "d:/Arquivos de Programas/XAMMP/xampp/mysql/data/"
port              = 3306
socket              = "MySQL"
```

**See? Have only put d: in front of the paths**. It seems that it comes only to run under the DEFAULT LOCATION.
I have it here, with only this modification running.
Have fun.

luis.closs@gmail.com