# "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)" when running the mysql command

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I diagnose ERROR 1045 during MySQL installation?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1923/how-should-i-diagnose-error-1045-during-mysql-installation)

The server runs on Ubuntu 9.10 64b.

I have installed mysql-server from source. The installation has completed successfully but when I run the `mysql` command in a terminal, I get following error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

What does that mean ? How do i rectify this error?

Answer (score 5):

You need to set a password before you can use it:

```
mysqladmin -u root password mysecret
```

After that, you can login with

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Comment: yeah..this works!

Comment: i found one more solution : http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-root@localhost-using-password-no-459578/     This is also working fine.